# pool heater pump electric wiring

Tags: electrical, wiring, electrical-panel, heater, pump

-- updated --

I want to plug my pool heater 50000 btu Jaccuzi JA50 ( on manual it says  AC208,230/60 1PH , circruit braker 20 A )

it has connection for
----power AC---
slot 1 L1 (red)
slot 2 L2 (black)
slot 3 ground
---- to pump --
slot 4 P1 (bleu)
slot 5 P2 (black) (which is connected to L2)

and I have an 230v nearby oultet which has 2 wires black + white and the ground , this outlet is plugged to 60A breaker (2x30) in the eletrical switchboard, the wall outlet model is NEMA 6-15 250v

my question :
I understand so I can wire directly my heater to this outlet (adding male connector) which I connect L1 to white and L2 to black ( I guess it doesn't matter )

is it correct this wiring and is it ok to use 50A breaker even if the heater says 20A ?

shall I use 30A cable as well ?

Thanks in advance
Joe

pictures :
https://ibb.co/8mmKvqX
https://ibb.co/Dp5Vztq
https://ibb.co/j6F3sqq
https://ibb.co/y4S6tKV
https://ibb.co/WKSYjPP
https://ibb.co/FVrhvN4
https://ibb.co/5Mb3NpZ
https://ibb.co/KXfMYDF

Comment: Can you post photos of the breaker, the outlet, and the nameplate on the heater?

Comment: https://ibb.co/8mmKvqX
https://ibb.co/Dp5Vztq
https://ibb.co/j6F3sqq
https://ibb.co/y4S6tKV
https://ibb.co/WKSYjPP
https://ibb.co/FVrhvN4
https://ibb.co/5Mb3NpZ
https://ibb.co/KXfMYDF

Comment: in fact it is 60A not 50A

Comment: Does this thing even permit cord-and-plug hookup to begin with? It looks like it was designed to be hardwired....

Comment: You realize a breaker that says 30A twice is a 30, not a 60, right?60A breakers literally say 60 on them.

Comment: correct I did a mistake to sum them :)  , I will hardwired them direct to panel and that's it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *...and I have an 230v nearby oultet which has 2 wires black + white and the ground , this outlet is plugged to 50A breaker in the
> eletrical switchboard, the wall outlet model is NEMA 6-15 250v*

A NEMA 6-15 receptacle is only rated for 15A, so if it is connected to a 50A breaker, that is dead wrong and an immediate fire hazard.

If the conductors are rated for 50A (6AWG if you are in North America), then there may be something usable here, but not the way it is. It would be difficult however to have connected #6 wire to a NEMA 6-15 receptacle, so it's not likely. If you can, take a picture of the outlet with the wires attached to it (turn off the power before removing it). IF it is #6 wire somehow, you may need special help in terminating it to a 20A receptacle. Report back what you find.

For a 20A circuit, you need #12 wire at a minimum, maybe #10 of the distance from the panel to the outlet is long. If you have that now, then you only need to change the outlet to a NEMA 6-20

All that said, I see the JA50 pump as being rated for 2A, not 20A. So I'm not sure where you are getting that info from. Maybe it says 20A MAXIMUM, but that would not preclude it from operating fine on a 15A circuit.If that's the case, your existing receptacle is fine, but the 50A circuit breaker is still not.

But also, is this a hot tub and if so, does it have electric heating? If that's the case, you likely DO need a 50A circuit to power the heaters + the pump. If it's gas heat though, then you only need the pump power.

Comment: I checked and found wrong labeling in fact the outlet is plugged to 60A (as I see 2x30 )

Comment: pictures are here : 

https://ibb.co/8mmKvqX
https://ibb.co/Dp5Vztq
https://ibb.co/j6F3sqq
https://ibb.co/y4S6tKV
https://ibb.co/WKSYjPP
https://ibb.co/FVrhvN4
https://ibb.co/5Mb3NpZ
https://ibb.co/KXfMYDF

Comment: Can't read the breaker handles in your picture, but if it says "30" on the handle, that's a 30A breaker, you don't add the two poles together to get 60A... The important information in your data plate is the "Minimum circuit ampacity", which says 15.2A, and the "Maximum fuse size", which says 25A. That is everything you need to know. If your breaker is truly 30A, that is too large for the heat pump, you need to change it to 25A. The good news is that if it is 30A, then the conductors would be #10, which is fine for this.#12 would be OK, but there is nothing wrong with being over sized.

Comment: much appreciated

Comment: ok I will change breaker to 20 A but is it ok to  connect L1 to white and L2 to black ?

Comment: White is supposed to be for the neutral (grounded conductor). If that is what they ran, I would get some red electrician's tape or red heat shrink tube to wrap over the white wire so that someone in the future will not think it is a neutral wire.